# Matrix of AppointmentItem

Tags: vba, outlook

Im trying to have my script return a list of appointmentitems. Im doing it like this:

```
Function testing() as AppointmentItem

Dim returnlist(10) as AppointmentItem
Dim item as AppointmentItem

for i = 0 to 9
    item = // create random appointmentitem
    Set returnlist(i) = item
next

testing = returnlist

End Function
```

The returnlist is filled correctly, however on the line `testing = returnlist` it gives me `Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try to use `Function testing() as AppointmentItem()` - with brackets at the end

Comment: That is exactly what went wrong. Thank you, make it an answer so I can reward you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return *array* of `AppointmentItem`'s, but not single `AppointmentItem`. Try this one:

```
Function testing() as AppointmentItem()
   Dim returnlist(10) as AppointmentItem
   Dim item as AppointmentItem

   For i = 0 to 9
      item = '// create random appointmentitem
      Set returnlist(i) = item
   Next

   testing = returnlist
End Function
```